# VBA to extract unique values from a list to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy, unique

In a past posting about copying unique values from one column to another on another worksheeet the code that was provided worked great except that it also copied the header  row of the data.

I've tried a number of ways to modify the code, but not being great at VBA I was unable to get it working. Can anyone modify this code so that it copied the unique values from one column to another except the header row?

```
Sub AdvFilter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, Frng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Flag Update (2)")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
    Set sh = Sheets("ICM flags")
    Set Frng = sh.Range("A:A")

    Frng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=rng, Unique:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: tip: you do not need to create the worksheet objects `ws` and `sh`, if you do not use them in other places in your code ... you can use code like this: `Set rng = Sheets("Flag Update (2)").Range("A1")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Module()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Range("A1:A10")
    .Copy .Offset(, 3)
    .Offset(, 3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to what your answer's code does. Code-only answers are more useful when paired with plain English descriptions. In other words... comment your code!